# Error 100 When Attempting to post from app to Facebook wall?

Tags: php, facebook, api, post, oauth

I'm playing around with the Facebook API, and have gotten far enough to get the access token into my app, but when I go to actually send a post to my Facebook wall I get the error message, `{"error":{"message":"(#100) You can't post this because it has a blocked link.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}1` I'm not attempting to send any kind of link, just "Hello, World!" so this seems pretty weird to me :\ Here's my code so far:

```
$content = urlencode("Hello, World!");
$accesstoken = urlencode($row['fbid']);    
$result = getPageWithPOST("https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed", "access_token=" . $accesstoken . "&message=" . $content);
echo $result;
```

where getPageWithPOST is,

```
function getPageWithPOST($url, $posts) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $posts);
    $content = curl_exec ($c);
    curl_close ($c);
    return $content; 
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you download and use the PHP SDK as it'll save you lost of hassles for many functions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/. Then there's a perfect eaxmple to copy on the following page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

But to directly answer the query: there doesn' appear anythign concrete on this error, but suggestiosn are that the server that you are posting from is probably blocked by Facebook - possibly a shared server that's been "banned" by Facebook? Try on a different server to see if you get better results.

Comment: ah, you're right :( I checked which IP address cURL was using, and then posted that to Facebook and sure enough, it was blocked. I'll try to contact Facebook and ask them to white-list my IP address and see if they agree. thanks :\

Comment: Thanks for confirming - that add more evidence as to what the error means! Good luck with the rest.